# Formatting BIGQUERY output for SQL Server-bound CSV

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I am using Airflow to move a table of data from bigquery to SQL Server.

The logical process is query the table, export to GCS, download local, and BCP into SQL Server.

```
Export_TABLE_to_GCS = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='Export_to_GCS',
    bigquery_conn_id='myconn1',
    source_project_dataset_table='database.dataset.table',
    field_delimiter='~',
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=['gs://dataset/table*.txt'],
    dag=dag
)

def DownloadFiles(set):
    gcsbucket = 'dataset'
    gcspath = '{}'.format(set)
    gcs = GoogleCloudStorageHook(gcp_conn_id='myconn1')
    gcs.get_conn()
    files = gcs.list(bucket_name=gcsbucket, prefix=gcspath)
    print(files)
    for file in files:
        print('downloading file {}'.format(file))
        gcs.download(gcsbucket, file, Variable.get("temp_directory") + "dataset/{}".format(file))


Export_GCS_to_Local = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Download_GCS_Files_to_Local',
    python_callable=DownloadFiles,
    op_kwargs={'set': 'dataset'},
    dag=dag
)

def bcp_in(set):
    files = []
    for file in glob.glob(Variable.get("temp_directory") + "dataset/{}*.txt".format(set)):
        files.append(file)
    print("LOCAL FILES {}".format(files))
    for file in files:
        print('Importing File {}'.format(file))
        cmd = '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp buyerhero_staging.dbo.{table} IN "{file}" -F2  -U<<USER>> -P<<Password>> -S<<Server>> -t"~" -c'.format(table=set, file=file)
        print(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8"))


BCP_Import_Files = PythonOperator(
    task_id='BCP_Import_Files_to_DB3_Staging',
    python_callable=bcp_in,
    op_kwargs={'set': 'dataset'},
    dag=dag
)
```

My problem is ingesting a column with a timestamp dataset.

Examples:

```
field1
---------------
2020-05-18 18:37:30
2020-05-18 20:19:11
2020-05-18 19:30:20
2020-05-19 08:27:35
2020-05-18 19:43:12
```

The problem is in the SQL. I created table1 by exporting a timestamp to string using:

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', field1) END AS field1
```

The format in the table works, and the table registers `string`. The table works and outputs in the webui ok. But when I export the table out to a csv, I get this:

```
2020-05-18 19:37:00 UTC      <-- notice the UTC
```

How do I get rid of the UTC? I know `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` is supposed to output to output to string. What am I missing?

Comment: FORMAT_TIMESTAMP() defaults to UTC when no time _zone parameter is specified so try giving it a time zone. A lot of the examples use "America/Los_Angeles".

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run the query `select FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', "2020-05-18 18:37:30")` it does not suffix with "UTC". When I export the table to GCS, it looks fine. Are you 100% sure that's the query you're using?

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you export table to GCS via `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator`?